# How to define a periodic function from an interval to Play (monotonic) sound

Tags: function-construction, sound

I would like to define a function on an interval and then duplicate it on other intervals of the same length in order to define a (generally discontinuous) periodic function, from which I could get a (monotonic) sound through [`Play`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Play.html).

How could I get that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a periodic function by this simple idiom

```
T = 1;
g[x_ /; 0 <= x <= T] := x^2;
g[x_] := g[Mod[x, T]]
```

Here, `T` is the length of the period. What happens is that you restrict your function `g` to a certain interval and when your argument `x` falls outside this interval, you just shift it back (using `Mod` here). With this, you can use `g` anywhere and it just repeats the interval [0,T]:

```
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can now be used for your sound to repeat a small piece:

```
f[t_ /; 0 <= t <= Pi] := Sin[t]*(Sin[880 Pi t] + Sin[1100 Pi t] + Sin[1320 Pi t]);
f[t_] := f[Mod[t, Pi]]

Play[Sin[t]*(Sin[880 Pi t] + Sin[1100 Pi t] + Sin[1320 Pi t]), {t, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! It works, thank you.