# Definition of a periodic function doesn't work when given as the forcing function of an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

I was using the nice function [how-to-define-a-periodic-function-from-an-interval-to-play-monotonic-sound](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95747/how-to-define-a-periodic-function-from-an-interval-to-play-monotonic-sound)  which works very well for defining a periodic function.

```
period=2;
g[t_/;0<=t<=period]:=t ;
g[t_]:=g[Mod[t,period]];
Plot[g[t],{t,0,3 period}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when I tried to use it as the forcing function of an ODE, Mathematica does not like it

```
 ode= x''[t]+2 x[t]==  g[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, why the above function definition does not work as shown above? And how to make it work? I need to define a period function as RHS of an ODE when I saw this definition given. I do not understand where the `Hold` is coming from.  Am I doing something wrong?

Mathematica 11.2 on windows 7

Comment: Fwiw your recursive g exhibits the same behavior when evaluated standalone.  Evaluating g[t] by itself gets the recursionlimit warnings, while g[1] works fine.  Being in a differential equation is not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not define `g`? directly in terms of `Mod`? Then there will be no problem with recursive calls.

```
period = 2;
Clear[g]
h[t_] := t/(1 + t^2)
g[t_] = h[Mod[t, period]];
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 3 period}]
```

[image: g_plot]

```
Clear[x]
ode = x''[t] + 2 x[t] == g[t];
x = NDSolveValue[{ode, x[0] == 1.25, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 3 period}];
Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 3 period}]
```

[image: x_plot]

Answer (score 2):

Since `g[t]` in general is defined recursively (without limit even, since `Mod[t,period]` does not actually guarantee that `0<=Mod[t,period]<=t` and the simplifications and assumptions that would allow that aren't likely to be called during the associated evaluation).

I suspect that if you're using `NDSolve` changing the second definition of `g[t]` to `g[t_?NumericQ]` will make it work fine. If you are intending to solve symbolically, then I would recommending substituting in `Mod[t,period]` for `t` in the first definition.